# fix error hidding status bar on ios 7

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

![Error hidden satus bar on ios 7[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIlrC.png)

I'm  problem when working on ios 7.
1. I'm want hidden status bar on ios7 when it build from xcode 4.6.
2.App current  is run on device ios 7 but status bar of Camera roll show a version older  of ios.

Can you help me about problem above?
Thanks so much.

Comment: I think you may need to supply more information in order to get any answers.  It really isn't clear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your view controller:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
 } else {
     // iOS 6
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
 }

 - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
     return YES;
  }
```

in **iOS 7**

please add this to your info.plist file, It will make the difference :)

```
UIStatusBarHidden UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance
```

[image]

Hope it will help.

Happy coding...:)